# Multiply Array items with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to implement this code:

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
a.multiply();
console.log(a); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

The result array needs to be concatenated at the end of the original array. I'm using the following code but it returns only the array with the values multiplied:

```
Array.prototype.multiply = function() {
    return this.map(function(item){return item * item})
}
a.multiply();
console.log(a); //[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: note that it's generally frowned upon to modify built-in object prototypes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could push the items of mapping to `this`.

```js
Array.prototype.multiply = function () {
    this.push(...this.map(v => v * v)); // push spreaded values
    return this;                        // allow fluent interface
};

var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

a.multiply();

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pardon me for asking but why mutate the array? You can decorate the Array prototype with functions which simply return the result you need. Mutating the input/state has its [disadvantages](https://medium.com/@jamesjefferyuk/javascript-what-are-pure-functions-4d4d5392d49c).

An approach where you **do not mutate** the array would be something like this:

```js
Array.prototype.multiplyAll = function() {
  return this.reduce((r,c) => r * c)
}
Array.prototype.multiplyEach = function() {
  return this.map(x => x * x)
}

var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(a.multiplyAll());
console.log(a.multiplyEach());
```

In general the recommended approach is [not to decorate the prototypes](https://lucybain.com/blog/2014/js-extending-built-in-objects/) of the build in Objects but to have a `utility` of pure functions with which you work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Array.concat" and "Array.map" like below

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// for direct method
function multiply() {
  return a.concat(a.map(d => d * d))
}

console.log(multiply(a));

// for prototype method
Array.prototype.multiply = function() {
    Object.assign(this, this.concat(this.map(d => d * d)))
}

a.multiply()

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're coding to the ES6 spec you can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in conjunction with `Array.prototype.map` method to achieve this. I re-named the method to `pushSquared` since I thought it made more sense.

```js
Array.prototype.pushSquared = function() {
  Object.assign(this, [...this, ...this.map(n => n * n)]);
}

var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
a.pushSquared()
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Though a seemingly clean solution, it's not changing `a` as asked in OP

Comment: @NitishNarang - You are correct. I updated the code.